# Enable "Did this answer your question" on mobile app

Tags: feature-request, android-app, duplicate-questions, ios-app

I am a strong users of the Stack Exchange Android app, and I noticed one big missing feature: Duplicate Questions working for me.

I posted a question on Super User, after searching for the answer. I did not see a duplicate, so I asked the question, giving as much detail as possible. In about half an hour, I get the buzz on my phone: `Possible duplicate: blah blah blah`. Hmmm...

I opened it on my mobile app, confirmed that yes, that question is a duplicate and has an answer. But, how do I confirm for future visitors?

I logged in on my computer, and was able to click the button saying the duplicate question had answered my question. I clicked the button, my question is put on hold as a duplicate, and life is all good.

I propose that we are given the option on the mobile apps to confirm that our own question *is in fact* a duplicate, just like on the main site.

Comment: Not sure about Android but the iOS app has a handy little "open in chrome" button so anything that you can't do in the app is easy enough to do in the browser. It's not ideal but it beats waiting till your back at a computer.

Comment: We have that option too, but I completely forgot that the OP can cast the binding "Yes" vote, until I got to my computer. It's a useful function I think that would benefit mobile users (like me)

Comment: I totally agree, it (along with a lot of other missing features) would be very useful.