# Voting to close as duplicate asks for question id or URL

Tags: bug, duplicate-questions, ios-app, close-dialog

I tried to close a question as a duplicate on [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/tour) meta. It already has three close votes, but the app still asked me for a question id/link without offering the current duplicate target.

[image]

- App Version: 1.6.1.2
- Device: iPhone 6
- OS Version: Version 10.0.2 (Build 14A456)

Comment: Duplicate here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/284720/245360

Comment: Or here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/277933/245360

Comment: @PatrickHofman the second one is better, though I felt it was a bug. Now, how do I accept the dupe via the app? Time for another feature request!

Comment: That would be a duplicate of http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/284642/245360.